# OD Matrix in Sumo and change files in Sumo only by xml

Tags: python, xml, matrix, openstreetmap, sumo

how can i import an OD matrix from excel to xml  and how can I change files in sumo only with xml?

```
$o;D2
* From_Time To-Time
0.00 1.00
* Factor
1.00
*some
*additional
*comments
            1         1          25
            1         2          31
            1         4          21
```

I have tried this but my table in excel contains many matrixes.

To change files in Sumo only by xml I have not tried yet.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to export the table from Excel using tabs as separator and insert the header manually. But if your Excel file contains many matrices in one sheet this may be difficult to separate.

Your question is a little unclear though, because your example shows neither Excel nor XML but the plain VISUM format.